# I can't understand how mono works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have started to learn Spring WebFlux and I can't understand how `Mono` works. What happens when we return `Mono` object as response from endpoint? Example:

```java
@PostMapping("/product")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Mono<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
    return productService.save(product);
}
```

How server process the request?

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Webflux subscribes to the `Mono` publisher returned by the controller method, extracts the `Product` instance **when it becomes available** and maps it to HTTP packets.